# How to close a web window created from gas

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm rendering a web window from google script.
After doing something at the end of the script I am not able to close the web window.
How can I close the opened window by gas.

This question can be replicated like the following

```
code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("clsWeb")  
}
function launchADummy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><body><script>window.onload = () => {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => { google.script.host.close();}).delay();};</script></body></html>';
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Dummy");
}

function delay() {
  return true;
}
clsWeb.HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <h1> How can I close this window from client or server </h1>
  <body>
    <script>
      google.script.run.launchADummy()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've done that by opening a dummy dialog that can close itself with google.script.host.close().  Opening the dummy will  close the webapp since you can only have one dialog at a time and  then you can issue google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(()=>google.script.host.close()).delay() where delay just returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function launchADummy() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><body><script>window.onload = () => {google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => { google.script.host.close();}).delay();};</script></body></html>';
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Dummy");
}

function delay() {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: My understanding is to put  the  launchADummy and  delay function  in code.gs and execute the script from HTML like the following.   google.script.run.launchADummy() is in  the .HTML page.  It does not close. Am I in the write direction? Please could you post the working  copy of code.gs and .HTML page here

Comment: I edit my post acording to your suggestions. Please examine it. What am I doing wrong

Comment: In my humble opinion this code would not achieve to close the current window. launchADummy() actualy is closing the opened created dumy window. but it is not closing the current window.

Comment: It works for me.  It closes the current window because Google Apps Script only allows one dialog at a time. Just try it.